# zookeeper connection timeout by error: Could not open client transport for any of the Server URI's in ZooKeeper

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, apache-zookeeper

I want to connect to zookeeper on default port (2181) and discover hive metastor by jdbc-url:
`jdbc:hive2://host:port/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2`
but i got error:
`Could not open client transport for any of the Server URI's in ZooKeeper: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect`
I check both hive and zookeeper(They are running) and in addition i can connect to other service like beeline and it's work but i could not connect through my jdbc-url

I appreciate anyone can help me

complete error message:

```
ERROR org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils - Unable to read HiveServer2 configs from ZooKeeper
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "org.jpype.JPypeContext.java", line -1, in org.jpype.JPypeContext.callMethod
java.net.ConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "org.jpype.JPypeContext.java", line -1, in org.jpype.JPypeContext.callMethod
org.apache.hive.org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: org.apache.hive.org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "org.jpype.JPypeContext.java", line -1, in org.jpype.JPypeContext.callMethod
Exception: Java Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/za-meysami/PycharmProjects/connect_to_hive/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    hive_driver_path)
  File "C:\Users\za-meysami\PycharmProjects\connect_to_hive\venv\lib\site-packages\jaydebeapi\__init__.py", line 412, in connect
    jconn = _jdbc_connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)
  File "C:\Users\za-meysami\PycharmProjects\connect_to_hive\venv\lib\site-packages\jaydebeapi\__init__.py", line 230, in _jdbc_connect_jpype
    return jpype.java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, *dargs)
java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport for any of the Server URI's in ZooKeeper: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

I try to connect to zookeeper and i get error of connection time-out